# dynamically added textarea are not render as TinyMCE

Tags: angular, tinymce

in angular I'm generating textAreas dynamically on button click after that I'm applying tinymce to the textAreas but tinymce was not applying to some of the textAreas. When I'm debugging the code to identify the issue tinymce is applied to every textArea but at the end of the method it was disappearing for some textAreas

my dynamically generated textAreas ids are like txtArea_1, textArea_2.....

I'm using following code to apply the tinymce to the textAreas

```
InitTinyMCE(): void {
    var txtIdArr = ['txtStem'];
    var i = 0;
    debugger;
    if (this.textArealist != undefined) {
        while (i < this.textArealist) {
            txtIdArr.push('txtAnswers_' + i);
            i++;
        }
        var j = 0;
        while (j < txtIdArr.length) {
            tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, txtIdArr[j]);
            tinymce.init({
                selector: txtIdArr[j],//'textarea',
                height: 100,
                theme: 'modern',
                menubar: false,
                statusbar: false,

            });
            tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, txtIdArr[j]);
            j++;
        }

    }
}
```

may I know the reason why it happens like that?